# Cocos2d iPHone SDK ccPhysicsCollisionPreSolve crashing while accessing object properties

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x-3.0, chipmunk

I am working on Cocos2d iphone SDK and stuck with an issues. Check my code here.

> Obstacle Class

```
@objc class Obstacle: CCNode {
    weak var __pipe: CCSprite!
    var ignoreCollision:Bool = false

    override init!() {
        super.init()
        //NSLog("init plain")
        userInteractionEnabled = true
        ignoreCollision = false
    }

    func didLoadFromCCB() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The main scene where I have placed collision delegate methods. The method is called once the player object collides with obstacle object.

```
func ccPhysicsCollisionPreSolve(pair: CCPhysicsCollisionPair!, hero: Player!, platform: Obstacle!) -> ObjCBool {
    if !isGameOn {
        NSLog("PLATFORM: Game finished")
        return false
    }

    if platform.ignoreCollision {
        platform.ignoreCollision = !platform.ignoreCollision
        // For score updates
        hudLayer.updatePlatform(++scorePlatforms)
    }

    return true
}
```

Now here, I am just trying to use simple `Bool` property from `platform` object and what I get is a crash. My app crashes on the `if...` condition statement where I am using that property. I am unable to get what is with this as I am simply using a property from object.

I checked the object and found `platform` shows me of type `Some` instead ob `Obstacle`. I have tried using

```
var p: Obstacle = platform as Obstacle
```

and replaced all `platform` with `p` but yet I am facing the crash. I thought the type now shows me some random hex number which might be the issue.

Can anyone help me here as I am unable to find out how I should access property from this `platform` object in `ccPhysicsCollisionPreSolve` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys for the trouble but it was my mistake. I was understanding the same incorrectly.

The `Obstacle` class represents the `platform` as well as its background layer having tripple height of the device screen. But my ball collides only with that `__pipe` sprite in `Obstacle` class and I am referring the whole `Obstacle` class which is wrong.

I used `platform.parent!.ignoreCollision` and problem is solved. :)
This little miss costed me 3-4 days of R&D and work extra.